# Getting error when I create a function which refers to values in a different row when using shift

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, shift

I'm trying to create a function which takes refers to values in a separate column as well as a value in an above row. I typically use shift to refer to values in an above row.

However, the shift function does not seem to work when I put it in a function.

I am receving the error "'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift' when I run the code below.

```
def don(df):
   if  df['C'] > df['55 day high'].shift(1):
        return 1
        
    else:
        return 0

df['regime']=df,apply(don,axis=1)
```

Comment: I suggest using `np.where()` instead of `apply`

Answer (score 0):

Your code failed because the function applied (*don*) receives
**only the current row** as its parameter.
Hence it has no access to the previous row (neither to the next row).

By the way: The way you named the param (*df*) suggests that the
function is given the **whole** DataFrame, which is not the case.
In such cases name rather this parameter as *row*.

And now how to do your task: A simpler (and faster) way to do your task is:

```
df['regime'] = (df['C'] > df['55 day high'].shift(1)).astype(int)
```